# How to resolve Angular update issue Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@13.3.11

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to update the current Angular 12 app to 13 using the official upgrade guide, but it fails. I am not sure what the issue is, frankly, I don't think the npm error messages are self-explanatory.

Here is the output:

```
PS C:\Projects\frontend> npx ng update @angular/cli@13
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 13.3.9 to perform the update.
✔ Package successfully installed.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 46 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular-devkit/build-angular @ "13.3.9" (was "12.2.18")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/cli @ "13.3.9" (was "12.2.18")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler-cli @ "13.3.11" (was "12.2.16")...
    Updating package.json with dependency typescript @ "4.6.4" (was "4.3.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/animations @ "13.3.11" (was "12.2.16")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/common @ "13.3.11" (was "12.2.16")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler @ "13.3.11" (was "12.2.16")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/core @ "13.3.11" (was "12.2.16")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/forms @ "13.3.11" (was "12.2.16")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser @ "13.3.11" (was "12.2.16")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @ "13.3.11" (was "12.2.16")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/router @ "13.3.11" (was "12.2.16")...
  UPDATE package.json (2773 bytes)
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: frontend@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.18
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~13.3.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~13.3.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@13.3.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.3.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~13.3.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Can someone tell me what the issue is and how to upgrade?

Comment: npx ng update? check again maybe? https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-13.0

Comment: why are you updating just the cli? what about angular/core?

Comment: @Carsten that's where I got the update command from. Leads to the error.

Comment: @thatOneDude both lead to the same issue. Was testing if one of them at a time may work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error appears because you have node 16.X or newer. Npm is stricter than before.

Solution 1:
downgrade your node version

Solution 2:
fix those erros by upgrading build-angular to 13.3.9

Comment: The update command updated "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.9". But the issue remains the same.

Comment: clean node and reinstall ? npm audit fix ?

Comment: I got it running but using --force and fixing old versions by hand. Not the best way, but it works. Thank you.

Comment: A slightly cleaner option than --force that worked for me is to add `legacy-peer-deps=true` in `.npmrc`, then retry. Probably want to remove that after the upgrade though. YMMV

Answer (score 9):

As suggested in a comment by @lyngvi this worked for me:

1. Create file .npmrc in your project root
2. add `legacy-peer-deps=true`
3. Commit .npmrc to git (or other scm, if any)
4. perform angular upgrade
5. (optionally) delete .npmrc

Answer (score 1):

In the [angular update guide](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=13.0-14.0), it suggest use ngx update commend bellow for update:

```
npx @angular/cli@13 update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13
```

and I got the conflicting peer dependency error:

```
    npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@13.3.12
    npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
    npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.3.10
    npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
    npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~13.3.10" from the root project
```

I change ngx command to specific angular version then it runs successfully:

```
npx @angular/cli@13.3.0 update @angular/core@13.3.0 @angular/cli@13.3.0
```